# Strange Out of Order Execution in onResume() Method

Tags: java, android

I have this code

```
  public void onResume() { // when onResume is called i want to if some member was deleted or added fee for a member 
    super.onResume();//because death of which activity causes the onresume call is a profile activity so maybe the member was deleted from that activity or fees was submitted for him
    Log.d("db","records on resume");
    if(ChangeNotifier.getInstance().isFeesAdded()){
        mAdapter.addItem(ChangeNotifier.getInstance().getAddedFee());
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mAdapter.getItemCount());
    }
    else if(ChangeNotifier.getInstance().isMemberDeleted()) // when member was deleted i call ChangeNotifier.getInstance.setMemberDeleted(true) , so now isMemberDeleted() will return true
    {
        Log.d("db","deleting");
        Member member = ChangeNotifier.getInstance().getDeletedMember();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < mAdapter.getItemCount() ; ++i) { // if the member was deleted i can delete him and his fee records from the recycler view 
            if(member.getMemberId().equals(mAdapter.getItem(i).first.getId())) {
                mAdapter.deleteItem(i);
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it is code for method isMemberDeleted()

```
 public boolean isMemberDeleted(){
    if(mMemberDeleted) {
        Log.d("db","yes deleted");
        mMemberDeleted = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is strange logcat

```
2020-03-12 21:20:47.367 8540-8540/com.bignerdranch.practice D/db: yes deleted
2020-03-12 21:20:47.368 8540-8540/com.bignerdranch.practice D/db: records on resume
```

**Strange thing one** the statement "yes deleted" is in `isMemberDeleted()` method as you can see in the code above and `Log.d("db","records on resume")` comes before this method is executed so how can it be in log cat after "yes deleted"

**Strange thing two** as you can see in code of `isMemberDeleted()` it is returning true the proof of this is that "yes deleted" was printed which is in same block , that means the code in `onResume()`

```
ChangeNotifier.getInstance().isMemberDeleted()

must have returned true so why the "deleting" was not in the logcat , which is first statement in the else if block as you can see in the code above
```

Can anyone please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isMemberDeleted()` is being called somewhere else in your code before onResume, at which point `mMemberDeleted` is being set to `false`, causing the block not to be entered within onResume.

Search the rest of your codebase for calls to `isMemberDeleted()` - it's one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Working Code.

> ```
> private boolean isDeleted(){
>     Log.v("ABCD","isdeleted fun");
>     return true;
> }
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>
>     Log.v("ABCD", "Start onResume");
>
>     if(!isDeleted()){
>         Log.v("ABCD", "IF");
>     }
>     else if(isDeleted()){
>         Log.v("ABCD", "IF ELSE");
>     }
>
>     Log.v("ABCD", "END onResume");
> }
> ```
>
> [image]
>   [image]

Comment: What is ChangeNotifier.getInstance().   Are you restarting activity again ? Try to comment all code and uncomment step by step to check where error is coming. Best way to check the flow to DEBUG. This may solve your problem. Otherwise you will hiding head to wall but no result found. Thanks bro.

Comment: check above image for debugging